# How to use Vue tags in Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, balde

**Hi, guys!**

I'm using Vue in my Laravel project. If I use Vue componet in Blade, it works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
   <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!-- it works -->
    <example-component></example-component>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I using Vue tags directly in Blade, it dosen't work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
   <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <!-- it dosen't work: Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined at index(xx) -->
    <v-app>
        <v-btn color="primary">I'm a Vue Button</v-btn>
    </v-app>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Thanks for answer:**

1. Vue is not defined...how to fix it?
2. Is this a wrong way to use Vue in Laravel Blade?
3. If this is a wrong way, please tell me the right way.

Comment: if you write like v-model in input tag then it is working?

Comment: thanks, but still the problem: Vue is not defined